# What's the non-negative, finite Borel measure whose Laplace transform is $e^{-\alpha r}, \alpha \geq 0$ fixed, that corresponds to Gaussian?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform, monotone-functions

**Just to give you a context** (but not directly related to my question, **so you can skip this paragraph and go to next one**): I've been reading http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf for a characterization of completely monotone functions, and I see that Theorem 2.5.2 (**Hausdorff-Bernstein-Widder theorem**) states that a characterization of  completely monotone function $\phi:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the Laplace transform of a finite non-negative Borel measure on $[0,\infty)$, i.e. equivalent to writing: $\phi(r)= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-rt}d\mu(t)$, where $\mu$ is a non-negative Borel measure on $[0,\infty)$. I'd like to find the non-negative Borel measure for the functions corresponding to Gaussian, as made explicit below.

**My question is:** Let $\alpha \geq 0$. Then what's a *finite*, *non-negative* Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$, satisfying: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-rt}d\mu(t)=e^{-\alpha r}   \forall r \in [0,\infty)$?

If we take: $d\mu(t):=\alpha dt$ on $[\alpha, \infty)$ and $0$ on $[0,\alpha)$, that satisfies the above equation, but $\mu$ isn't finite in this case.

Comment: A point mass at …

Comment: Oh my, why didn't I think about that first, a point mass or Dirac mass at $\alpha$, i.e. $\mu:= \delta_{\alpha}$ would do the job! Thank you!!

Comment: Would an error function work as well for $\mu$?